# How can I make this alphabetical list look nicer in the output in python

Tags: python, list, file-io

It works for the most part but the output looks well messy as hell so how might I be able to clean it up I would also like to know how to phrase the pseudocode if possible.

```
#open file with list
infile  = open("unsorted_fruits.txt", "r") 
#open file writing to
outfile = open("sorted_fruits.txt", "w")      
#create variable to work with list
all_lines = infile.readlines()              
for line in all_lines:                      
    print (line,)          

#this function has sorted other list
def insertion_sort(list):                   
    for index in range(1, len(list)):
        value = list[index]
        i = index - 1
        while i >= 0:
            if value < list[i]:
                list[i+1] = list[i]
                list[i] = value         
                i = i - 1               
            else:
                break  

#calling the function to sort 
insertion_sort(all_lines)                   
all_sorted = str(all_lines)                                                                  
#print list to show its sorted
print (all_sorted)
#write the sorted list to the file
outfile.write(all_sorted)                                    

infile.close()                              
outfile.close()
exit()
```

Input:papaya

kiwifruit

zapote blanco

huckleberry

banana

fig

lime

xigua

vanilla

yiessas

tamarind

umkolo

quince

apple

imbu

elderberry

juneberry

mango

strawberry

nectarine

date

cherry

orange

watermelon

grape

raspberry

Output: ['\n', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n', 'apple\n', 'banana\n', 'cherry\n', 'date\n', 'elderberry\n', 'fig\n', 'grape\n', 'huckleberry\n', 'imbu\n', 'juneberry\n', 'kiwifruit\n', 'lime\n', 'mango\n', 'nectarine\n', 'orange\n', 'papaya\n', 'quince\n', 'raspberry\n', 'strawberry\n', 'tamarind\n', 'umkolo\n', 'vanilla\n', 'watermelon\n', 'xigua\n', 'yiessas\n', 'zapote blanco\n']

Comment: Would you mind posting the input and output files?

Comment: Sure just did that for you

Answer (score 0):

This is probably due to the file having extra newlines at the end of the file which are being picked up in the `readlines()` function.

When you go to print each item in your final list, just filter out those that are new lines only:

```
for word in all_sorted:
    if word.rstrip('\n'):
        print(word.rstrip('\n'))
```

The `rstrip()` function (right-strip) strips all newlines at the end of a word. If the word is only a new line, then rstrip will return an empty string, which is filtered out by the if statement.

Comment: @TonyBruno At the end. I assume you wanted to print the results? Or nah?

Comment: @TonyBruno Oh, apologies, did you want to write each word to the file? Change `print(word.rstrip('\n'))` in my code to `outfile.write(word.rstrip('\n'))`

Comment: Did you paste this text into idle with my code to test it because adding this seems to just make the output have each letter take up a line without taking away \n and the output text is unchanged.

Comment: @TonyBruno OHH you converted the list to a string. Sorry - replace `all_sorted` with `all_lines`. does that work?

Comment: Yes mostly but now they have no space between them or even a , in the output.

Comment: It comes out better print wise and then comes out wrong and the output comes out with no spaces or ","

Answer (score 0):

It's not really the output that's the problem here.  It's the way you read the list of fruits.  You really want to sort *fruits*, not *lines*.

Many of the lines in the input file are blank, and you don't want to include them.  And you probably don't really want to consider the trailing '\n' as part of each fruit, either.

So instead of iterating through infile.readlines(), I recommend iterating through infile.read().splitlines().  That will automatically strip the trailing \n.  And while you're at it, you can drop the blank lines.

```
with open('unsorted_fruits.txt', 'r') as infile:
    fruits = [f for f in infile.read().splitlines() if f != '']
```

Then you can sort fruits instead of lines.  And if you don't want then the final output to be written as the string representation of a Python list, you can use print().

```
for fruit in fruits:
    print(fruit, file=outfile)
```

Or file.writelines()

```
outfile.writelines(f + '\n' for f in fruits)
```

Comment: Any chance you could post the code with this fully integrated so I can test it a little easier?

Comment: Oh this is for a specific task to make it without using builtin sort

Comment: Sorry, I didn't integrate this with your code.  I just used the built-in sort to test it.

Comment: Can you maybe integrate it to see if it works or if you can help me meet the criteria I need to meet and make the output look nice

Comment: It works.  I tested it with the built-in sort.  You asked how to fix the output, and the output doesn't depend on which function was used to sort the fruits.

Answer (score 0):

Now the output file looks like this using this code. Anyone have advice to make it look nicer. 
applebananacherrydateelderberryfiggrapehuckleberryimbujuneberrykiwifruitlimemangonectarineorangepapayaquinceraspberrystrawberrytamarindumkolovanillawatermelonxiguayiessaszapote blanco['\n', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n', 'apple\n', 'banana\n', 'cherry\n', 'date\n', 'elderberry\n', 'fig\n', 'grape\n', 'huckleberry\n', 'imbu\n', 'juneberry\n', 'kiwifruit\n', 'lime\n', 'mango\n', 'nectarine\n', 'orange\n', 'papaya\n', 'quince\n', 'raspberry\n', 'strawberry\n', 'tamarind\n', 'umkolo\n', 'vanilla\n', 'watermelon\n', 'xigua\n', 'yiessas\n', 'zapote blanco\n']

```
#open file with list
infile  = open("unsorted_fruits.txt", "r") 
#open file writing to
outfile = open("sorted_fruits.txt", "w")      
#create variable to work with list
all_lines = infile.readlines()              
for line in all_lines:                      
    print (line,)          

#this function has sorted other list
def insertion_sort(list):                   
    for index in range(1, len(list)):
        value = list[index]
        i = index - 1
        while i >= 0:
            if value < list[i]:
                list[i+1] = list[i]
                list[i] = value         
                i = i - 1               
            else:
                break  

#calling the function to sort and make it look nicer
insertion_sort(all_lines)
for word in all_lines:
    if word.rstrip('\n'):
        print(word.rstrip('\n'))
for word in all_lines:
    if word.rstrip('\n'):
       outfile.write(word.rstrip('\n'))

all_sorted = str(all_lines)

#write the sorted list to the file
outfile.write(all_sorted)                                    

infile.close()                              
outfile.close()
exit()
```